# Flutter stuck on Building Dart code after doing flutter build ios

Tags: ios, dart, flutter

I'm trying to build an archive by doing `flutter build ios` but I encounter a problem on `Starting Xcode build`

```
$ flutter build ios

Building com.example.example for the device (ios-release)...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified 
development team in Xcode project: XXXXXX
Running pod install...                                       
Starting Xcode build...
  ├─Building Dart code...
```

I already build an archive one (last week) and it was working. Maybe this is due to flutter upgrade ?

```
$ flutter doctor

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.11.3, on Mac OS X 10.14.1 18B75, locale 
en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK  
28.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.29.1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an issue that was fixed very recently and the fix should already be available in the `master` channel.

```
flutter channel master
flutter doctor
```

You can also try `dev` channel, but I'm not sure if it landed there already.
The fix will of course be included in the next `beta` channel, but a `beta` release just came out last week, so it will probably take a while to the next.

See also https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24139

Comment: It's working thanks !
Should I always work on master channel then ? I'm very new to flutter

Comment: No, preferred is `beta`, but Flutter is moving fast and sometimes things can break and then are first fixed in master and after a while dev and later beta are updated. Use master or dev if beta doesn't work. Master is first to get fixes but also breaks more often.