# Flutter App stuck at "Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... "

Tags: gradle, flutter, yaml, flutter-dependencies

When I run the app it get stuck

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Lenovo A319 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
(This is taking an unexpectedly long time.)
```

It never initialize Gradle nor the dependencies

Comment: `(This is taking an unexpectedly long time.)` does it mean after that time it gives back a certain result? if yes, what's the result?

Comment: is this the first time ? or was it working before ?

Comment: Are you connected to the internet? If so, please check your internet connection--assuming dependencies are not yet cached locally on your machine. Also can you please try sharing the logs after running `flutter run -v`. Lastly, you can try stopping an existing gradle daemon via `cd android && ./gradlew --stop` then run the `flutter run -v` again.

Comment: The information you provided is not enough to know the cause you of the delay. You should provide the output of `flutter doctor`, this will narrow the bug search area. Does it do that will a specific app or all your apps?

Comment: Hi, after waiting nearly waiting 10 mins
[Log](https://pastebin.com/A4hUt9rb) 
the app doesn't show what it suppose to show

Comment: @LoïcFonkam everything is fine with flutter doctor, my app is also stuck with the same error, up to 20+ minutes, then it run successfully if do want to know why does this happen

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In my case, Windows Firewall was causing this problem. After I disabled it temporarily the problem was gone. Worth giving it a try. Good luck!

Comment: I can't believe this but this is true for Windows 10

Comment: I had the same problem with Avast Antivirus

Comment: Even this is true for Windows 11, too!

Comment: In my case it was Acronis blocking it!

Comment: Mine too, how do I permanently permit it through firewall?

Comment: does anyone know if this is this also the case for Mac OS?

Answer (score 230):

Here is solution in my case.

1. Open your flutter Project directory.
2. Change directory to android directory in your flutter project directory `cd android`
3. clean gradle `./gradlew clean`
4. Build gradle `./gradlew build` or you can combine both commands with just `./gradlew clean build`
5. Now run your flutter project. If you use vscode, press F5. First time gradle running assembleDebug will take time.

PS: Delete gradle in case of all that steps don't work

Comment: Not sure if it will work, but deleting a folder with over 80.000 files feels incredibly pleasant. Definitely ~/.gradle went out of hand

Comment: Hi. I edited the order of deleting gradle from main flow. 
Because most of the case solved by following step 2-6. Step 1 (deleting gradle) is optional in case of step 2 -6 not worked.

Comment: it seems running but i have code error in my project

Comment: after running gradlew.bat clean build from the .gradle directory it showed the download progress, 6minutes in and still downloading jar files, thanks for the answer

Comment: This gave me error `Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache`, which I resolved with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64637310/6422750).

Comment: Is there any way, automatically downloading files from fast mirror (while it is downloading)

Comment: This answer worked for me in that I discovered I didn't have my Java classpath set when running `gradlew clean`.

Comment: Alright this worked fine for me but is there a way to fix this for every new Flutter project?

Comment: Getting No Such File or Directory

Comment: why is it so slow ? It tales me 5 minutes for a project with 3 files...

Comment: It works. FYI, whats helping is when you run `./gradlew clean build`, it gave us informations about the problem in android side, so you can fix it. In my case, i have to change SDK Version, due to library i installed. But, it took > 20 minutes for me

Comment: Now I got stuck too when running gradle clean. Lmfao.

Comment: step 5 is the best. always work for me

Answer (score 153):

`flutter run -v` showed that I was stuck on

`Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip`

This was going to take hours, as for some reason the download speed was ~10kB/s on a decent DSL connection.

Solution:

1. Interrupt gradle build
2. Download the required gradle zip from a [fast mirror](https://distfiles.macports.org/gradle/). e.g.   https://distfiles.macports.org/gradle/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
3. Copy `gradle-5.6.2-all.zip` to `C:\Users\ <MyUsername>\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.2-all\9st6wgf78h16so49nn74lgtbb` (of course the last folder will have a different name on your PC)
4. `flutter run` and voilà.

Comment: I was lazy to change anything, waited forever to see if it's gonna work and eventually it worked. So I guess it actually works, but as you said download speed is super slow.

Comment: By using this command I can see that the problem comes from downloading files.. It could be a good idea for flutter team to increase the default logging level, when the app is launched from Android Studio, the user has no clue about what's going on! Thanks for the tip :-)

Comment: gradle got me every single time. Whenever I do new setup... I have to do this.

Comment: flutter run -v this command made the day. You again proved Flutter has many built-in great debugging  tools that we forgot to use

Comment: after flutter run -v i noticed i was stuck because of invalid app id for admob in mainfest file , Thanks

Answer (score 20):

If you are on Windows:
try adding firewall exceptions to your Android Studio.

1. Go to:

   > Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Defender Firewall\Allowed apps
2. Hit the button:

   > Allow another app
3. Add your new firewall exceptions:

   > studio.exe and studio64.exe

I hope this can be useful for you too.

Answer (score 19):

If Running Gradle task assembledebug is taking unexpectedly long time,
try updating Gradle in your project. (Downloading latest zip file)

You can follow steps in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60691179/11690853).

Or try by:

1. Open a project in Android Studio
2. Right-click on android in Projects Panel
3. Go down to Flutter and click on the 'Open Android module in Android Studio'.

(See screenshot for reference)

[image: Steps 1 to 3]

This should open the project as an Android Project.

4. Now, click on 'gradle' in the right panel.
5. Next, click on 'Execute Gradle Task' icon

[image: Steps 4 and 5]

This should open a 'Run Anything' window.

6. Now, Run the command  `gradlew clean`
7. and, then run   `gradlew build`
8. If prompted by Android Studio to 'Update Gradle Plugin', do that.

[image: Update Gradle Plugin]

The update would download the required .zip files.
And, your apps should work fine after that.

Comment: "3. Go down to Flutter and click on the 'Open Android module in Android Studio' "But my ```Flutter``` is disabled. In another flutter project which can run sucessful, the ```Flutter``` is enabled. Do you know why?

Comment: It did show Flutter disabled in certain cases. In that instance, you can instead use the terminal to do this as mentioned in the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60691179/11690853

Comment: Thank you. And I solved the problem by upgrade the ```compileSdkVersion``` to 31. The ```flutter``` is still disabled but it just doesn't matter.

Answer (score 10):

**I am using VS Code on Ubuntu 18.04**

For me it was a background download of the appropriate android sdk build tools for my connected device. Running `flutter run -v` showed that it was downloading android SDK build tools which usually take some time. Once it was done, the flutter app compiled and ran successfully.

**Solution**

1. Ensure you have installed android sdk tools and added them to the environment path.
   I assume you have downloaded android sdk tools.
2. Ensure you have installed gradle and added it to the path
3. Ensure you have installed latest dart and flutter sdks

For no 1 and 2 please refer to this post:

[Setting up flutter without Android studio](https://dev.to/jay_js/setting-up-flutter-without-android-studio-olo)

Answer (score 6):

For me what worked was clean wipe the emulator data by AVD Manager

[image: Wipe data by AVD Manager]

Comment: This was the only solution in the whole thread that worked for me!

Answer (score 5):

There were two reasons for me on Archlinux:

1. I needed to `unset TERM` which was set to `xterm-256color` ([reference](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4426)).
2. For some reason, flutter stable was not working for me; so I switched to master with: `flutter channel master` && `flutter upgrade`. I'll be able to switch back to flutter stable when the fix in master makes its way into stable ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53365216/5057805)).

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm also on arch and have been trying to understand why it isn't working for 1½ day now.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me.I got an issue with license acceptance.
First you need to go through the flutter directory and then run the command

```
C:\Users\thrishool\flutterProjects\flutter>flutter doctor
```

Then it will display if everything is fine or not.I got an issue that, I didnot accept all the licenses.So you need to accept them all.Now type this in cmd

```
C:\Users\thrishool\flutterProjects\flutter>flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Accept all the licenses and you are good to go.

Answer (score 4):

This is likely one of number of issues and some of the recommended troubleshooting can be found [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47392).

1. Check that you are building against an Android sdk that you have
   installed... in your build.gradle file check the compileSdkVersion.
2. You can try uninstalling and reinstalling the relevant SDK.
3. Some users have reported that they had to resintall Dart.

Without a little more information basic troubleshooting is the best we can offer sorry.

Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

I used the command "flutter clean" in my project and it returned to work perfectly, please try.
[Igual a imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iNgk.png)

```
flutter clean
```

Answer (score 4):

For me simply the process took too much time. It kept running for about 10 mins and finally the app started running.

Comment: Indeed, mine took nearly 15 min or so

Answer (score 3):

This problem occurred on my system because of the Zen Kernel.

I installed the Linux-LTS kernel and started system using this.

Then my project backed to compile again.

Answer (score 2):

For creating an apk for Android in Flutter this issue sometimes happens. I had the luck of facing this issue as well. Here are the few ways it can be solved:

```
1. Due to androidX
```

If you followed recommended route from here:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

Try this:

Check with steps in “not recommended” way in above tutorial if every listed files is same as in your project, especially :
in `root/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties set distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip`

in `root/android/build.gradle, set
dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2' }`

check if `root/android/app/build.gradle SDK version is set to minimum 28 for:
compileSdkVersion 28 and targetSdkVersion 28`
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio:

Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter clean.

After that just run the app

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled on this problem when I was running my app without debugging it. Theres two option

1. Start Debugging
2. Run without Debugging

I was doing the second option the whole time which got me stuck in that running graddle loop. I fixed my problem with the first option.

Answer (score 2):

1: If it is the first launch, please be patient since it will download all gradle files for the first time.

2: To know if it really stuck, take help from the task manager in windows or the activity monitor on Mac, and check if the process is really using some CPU or network or not. If not, it is stuck. If it is using some resources, please be patient then (it should take ~5-40 minutes normally, even if you have slower internet).

3: If it is really suck, stop the process and run `./gradlew clean` before building it next time.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue because of the wrong compileSdkVersion in the build.gradle file.
Working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I forgot to download Google Web Driver.
It’s running once I downloaded Google Web Driver.

Answer (score 1):

It is taking time on windows 10 as the Android studio needs firewall permission to connect to the device(AVD). 
There can be another reason that you don't have downloaded full Android SDK on your machine.
To check the issue simply run the command on your terminal/cmd/PowerShell command tool.

`flutter doctor`[flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trGih.png)

check if SDK is installed or not.
Try to install and accept license using the following command

`flutter doctor --android-licenses`

If this doesn't resolve your problem then go to android studio and Open your Android Studio,

`File-> settings->System settings(left tab) ->Android SDK`
,

go to 
`SDK Tool section` 
in that page,

untick `hide obsolete packages`,

select `Android SDL tools(obsolete)` 
and press apply also install other useful tools according to your convenience.

Answer (score 1):

This helped: check if root/android/app/build.gradle SDK version is set to minimum 28 for:
compileSdkVersion 28 and targetSdkVersion 28

Occurs with import of Firestore.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the Android Gradle Plugin Version was not updated to any version at all. So i updated it by right clicking on my project folder, clicked "Open Module Settings" and updated gradle plugin version accordingly.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I need to update Android SDK built-tools.

Open in Android studio `Tools->SDK Manager-SDK tools`.
Mark Android SDK Built-Tools, press Apply, wait for the update.
After updated, press Apply and try to run.

[image: android SDK built-tools]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by switching off my antivirus while running my project in the terminal

To run your project in a terminal simply type --> flutter run

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

C:\Users<user>\AndroidStudioProjects<flutter_app>\android> **gradlew clean**
C:\Users<user>\AndroidStudioProjects<flutter_app>\android> **gradlew build**

Now run it, for initial build

```
“Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'… ”
```

will take 10-12 mins after that it will be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the required gradle zip from a fast mirror: https://distfiles.macports.org/gradle/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
2. Copy gradle-5.6.2-all.zip to C:\Users
   .gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.2-all\9st6wgf78h16so49nn74lgtbb

If this does not work, go to android studio's terminal then run:- flutter run.

See what SDK platform it's asking you. like SDK API 28, 29, or 30.
Then goto SDK manager and install the required SDK API. Then restart android studio.

It will work perfectly fine!!

Answer (score 1):

The same problem occurred on my mac in Android Studio 4.1, unfortunately, I forgot to install Java on my machine, try installing Java.

Comment: And don't forget to set JAVA_HOME environment variable, this happened to me

Answer (score 1):

nothing was working for me

I do update the flutter SDK & update all the dependencies to the latest version. after that, I open the `android` module as a project in android studio. It downloads some files. after completion, I do clean the project using `Build->clean Project` & update the Gradle version.

After that, I again open the flutter project and run the app. It's working now.... :)

Answer (score 1):

This might also be due to **developers permission**, if you will be using any package which requires devices permission lets say `url_launcher` and you haven't given permission for that it wont run. Solution for windows is that just run `ms-settings:developers` this in your command prompt/ powershell and enable for developers option and then it will work fine.
and if that doesnt also works then just run `flutter clean` and `flutter create .` it will work.

Answer (score 0):

How are you !,

After many attempts, nothing they recommended worked for me.

My problem was that I had * .dart files with many lines of code to perform SQL create and insert operations initially in SQLite, I removed those 4072 lines of operations, the file was reduced in size and I no longer had to compile a very code file long, instead, I preloaded the database into assets, and it worked flawlessly! ..

The message that the operation is taking a long time no longer appears, I hope it serves you.

[Before, when long file size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmIG8.png)

[After, without SQL code operations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPF2Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by reinstalling SDK Platform on Android studio for Android API 29

```
Tools->SDK Manager-SDK Platform
```

Next go to

```
Android > app > build.gradle
```

Make sure you also change

```
compileSdkVersion 29

targetSdkVersion 29
```

Be patient, it take longer for the first launch...But, not take forever like before.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

With my LG G6 I have the same issue.
It looks like the new versions of adb added some compatibility issues with some LG phones.

Downgrading to platform-tools version 28.0.0 solved the problem.

References:

https://superuser.com/questions/1357708/android-adb-logcat-works-only-on-shell/1357929#1357929

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18889#issuecomment-421432066

Answer (score 0):

Finally i fixed it.
The problem is mostly due to android SDK or  gradle built tool

There are different ways you can try to fix it.
way 1. check whether google drivers are installed . you can find them in sdk manager of the android studio

way 2. flutter doctor -v
flutter doctor --android-licenses  (#this will check whether all the licenses of android are accepted)

way 3.  flutter clean;flutter build apk
flutter run    ( In the start it will take time for assembledeubg so kindly be patient for 7 to 10 mins)

way 4. If this also do not work
flutter clean
flutter run     (be patient and finally after 5 to 10 min your flutter code will run on the emulator)

Hope these solutions work for you, If not reply me back.

Answer (score 0):

In my case **installing** **JDK** solved the problem.

**macOS Catlina** v10.15.4

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried that from cli ?

flutter devices

flutter run

https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/test-drive?tab=terminal

In a mac environment, the building process finished in 140s.

Answer (score 0):

do `flutter clean` first
then **copy your project folder somewhere else**
close your project and open same project which is copied diffrent location.
thats it !!

Answer (score 0):

If you already opened a project and create another new project, make sure that you update the Gradle file based on the already runnable project version. In my case, I already installed Gradle 5.6.4 on a previous project and when I create a new project, it was 5.6.2 in the Gradle wrapper file. So I updated it.

Answer (score 0):

If Running Gradle task assembledebug is taking unexpectedly long time and if its not working even after checking the solutions mentioned in this article.

Just go and create new virtual device in AVD Manager. I hope this will definitely work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was, project_path contained "space".

Example:

```
~/New Folder/myProject
```

Check if you have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved using following:

1. in android studio **tools--> sdk Manager --> android sdk--> sdk platforms**. dowload android sdk platform 28
   [image: dowload android sdk platform 28]

now re-run ur project

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with upgrading flutter version from `2.0.5` to `2.2.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Can run the flutter app in profile / release mode to launch the app quickly. Note: We suppose to relax the hot reload. [mode details](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/build-modes)

[image: select profile mode run]

Answer (score 0):

if u are using windows 10,
open your project in the terminal, and write these commands:

1. cd android
2. gradlew clean
3. gradlew build

then run the project.

Note: if u face a problem like no path for JAVA_HOME so set this path
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre   in the environment variable.
and open project structure in android studio and set the same path in JDK path.

Answer (score 0):

This solution should be working for some cases:

1 - Download Google Web Driver in Android SDK.

2 - Update Dart And Flutter in IntelliJ Idea or Android Studio or VS Code plugin.

3 - Run again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge, meanwhile, doing flutter clean, flutter doctor, download gradle didn't help me and my issue stayed again. Finally the bellow steps rescued me from this trap.

```
1)Create a new flutter project(File--> new flutter project)
2)Transfer Lib, assets, font, pubspec.yaml, pubspec.lock 
3)pub update in pubspec.yaml of new project
4) change the kotlin version to latest version like 1.5.10 in android/build.gradle path in new project.
```

At the end try to rebuild your project and solve the other tiny problems which maybe occur. For instance, in my project the mentioned steps help me precisely.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue today, every solution I found didn't work. In my case, I had to update Windows, after installing every update they listed and then restarting pc, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for almost half a day, so what I did :

- Go to my Home directory, enabled show hidden folders.
- Delete the `.gradle` folder.
- Went back to Android studio, opened the terminal, and ran the `flutter run`  command.
- After it completes, the app will be launched on your connected device.

> Note: Make sure you have a strong internet connection because gradle files are going to be re-downloaded.

Thank you, hope this one helps

Answer (score 0):

for me, I just changed my proxy, while I have problem on sync gradle files on my country.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just restart my computer and it's fixed. Probably it's happening because of lack of some files while launching the app.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot edit other answeres so here is mine on top of answere from @Sébastien.

first use `flutter run -v` or of you are using **Android Studio**, edit `project configurations` and add -v to the `Additional run args`

after that running project shows that in my case gradle downloading is taking too much time, so download it directly and unzip it in: `C:\Users\ <MyUsername>\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.2-all\9st6wgf78h16so49nn74lgtbb`

some notes about this address:

1. gradle folder should be the same name as the file you downloaded so if it ends in `bin` instead of `all`, use that
2. the hash at the end is created by default when graddle wrapper starts the download but these are some common ones on my system:

   `gradle-7.1-bin`:`4pslxx9lrxt5svtz5wbnb6tkz`

   `gradle-7.2.1-all`:`2hmet7i3y4pg69r05wkkofsqn`

   `gradle-7.3.3-all`:`4295vidhdd9hd3gbjyw1xqxpo`

   `gradle-7.5-all`:`6qsw290k5lz422uaf8jf6m7co`

   `gradle-7.5.1-all`:`1ehga6e77gqps5uk2kc5kf1vc`

**NOTE** inside the said folder there is a file ended in `.part`, that is the partially downloaded gradle file, if it is there gradlew will try to complete it, so change the `.part` to `.ok`, ex: `gradle-7.5-all.zip.part` -> `gradle-7.5-all.zip.ok` you can also delete it and use an empty file to save some space

Answer (score 0):

I opened editing of the project in Android Studio from Tools menu then I found out it was trying to download **gradle-7.5-all.zip** but no progress. Now from ***/home/myusername/.gradle/wrapper/dists*** folder I have other version (8.0) of gradle already downloaded:
[image]
So I closed the project editing. Then from the ***projectname/android/gradle/wrapper*** folder:

[image]

I changed the gradle version in the distribution url to **gradle-8.0-bin.zip** and reopen the project editing in Android Studio and I can see the syncing and indexing required gradle files. Though it still takes some time but I can see the progress so I waited for it to complete then run the app and it works!.

Answer (score -1):

Just connect with internet then disable your windows defender/firewall. It works for me.

Answer (score -2):

On android studio go to file/invalidate caches/

For me this works

Answer (score -3):

`taskkill /F /IM dart.exe` then `flutter clean`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I have tried all these methods but still it is stuck at assemble gradle debug. This issue never happened before. Please help