# how to solve the assemble debug issue.?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

**Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Note 5 Pro in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1**
 this is the error showing in the run log when im trying to run the demo flutter codes.

Comment: Which Android Studio version? Which demo codes? Did you install the Flutter and Dart plugins?

Comment: Android version 4.0 , plugin of both flutter and dart were installed. While creating a new project in flutter , some codes are pre written which can be installed.

Comment: refer to this link [Assemble-debug-fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59516408/flutter-app-stuck-at-running-gradle-task-assembledebug)