# Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache

Tags: java, windows, android-studio, flutter, windows-10

I've been using Flutter on Android Studio. Today, I updated it and everything went downhill.

I've been having different errors throughout my attempt to fix this.

First error: could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.invokerhelper

Second error: could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache

[image]

Anyways, I've been researching and I've done the following

1. Updated Java SDK.
2. Updated JRE
3. Added necessary paths to environment variables
4. Updated Gradle

**But nothing is still working and I cannot run my project. Please help?**

Here are some screenshots of my different attempts:
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Got any solutions that worked? I am having literally same problem. Respond soon, take care.

Comment: @DetainedDeveloper Yes. I finally fixed it by uninstalling anything beyond Java 8. It seems like Android Studio doesn't like upgraded Java. Everything works now that I reverted it.

Comment: Well, I tried the answer by @MickaellHrndz, that didn't work initially, it worked after I changed gradle version to 6.5 instead of 6.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally fixed it by uninstalling anything beyond Java 8. It seems like Android Studio doesn't like upgraded Java. Everything works now.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem a few days ago. I fixed it by updating the Gradle version in `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` to :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip
```

For it to update, you just have to `flutter run`.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by updating gradle version.

1. Go to android->gradle->wrapper->gradle-wrapper.properties file and update gradle to latest version.

   ```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
   ```
2. Go to android->build.gradle file

   ```
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
   ```
3. `flutter clean`
4. `flutter run`

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you get any error when you run

---

```
flutter doctor
```

in terminal.

2. Did you run

---

```
flutter clean
```

in terminal from your project folder?

Comment: [!] Android Studio (not installed)
[√] VS Code (version 1.50.1)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.40.2)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

Comment: The error clearly says : [!] Android Studio (not installed) . Please try to reinstalling Android Studio.