# Flutter running gradle task 'assembledebug' ... long time, stucked

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, long-integer

I am a newbie here, my problem is similar to: [Flutter App stuck at "Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59516408/flutter-app-stuck-at-running-gradle-task-assembledebug)

In fact I guess the problem was my laptop shut down while running app on my device, maybe something went wrong during that, and now it just loading and loading but stuck, for a long time (almost 2 hours)

1. I tried gradlew clean and build but also nothing appeared, too long.
2. Tried flutter clean, nothing. (anyway any gradle command not even show reply on console)
3. Tried download the gradle manually and invalidate cache, (still running ~ 2 hours)
4. Tried download manually and set the classpath manually to the jar (other tab, still running ~2 hours)

My project is working on desktop and on web, except phone. (I don't use emulator)

How long does it take to download these? Only patience and will work, or what would you suggest.
UPDATE: Waited 2-3 hours, nothing, so I think something else is the problem.

Here is the flutter run -v logs:

`[  +28 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... [   +8 ms] Using gradle from C:\Flutter\projects\dummy\android\gradlew.bat. [  +34 ms] executing: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version [ +137 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version [        ] openjdk version "1.8.0_212-release" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b04, mixed mode) [   +2 ms] executing: [C:\Flutter\projects\dummy\android/] C:\Flutter\projects\dummy\android\gradlew.bat -Pverbose=true -Ptarget-platform=android-arm64 -Ptarget=C:\Flutter\projects\dummy\lib\main.dart -Pdart-defines=RkxVVFRFUl9XRUJfQVVUT19ERVRFQ1Q9dHJ1ZQ== -Pdart-obfuscation=false -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Ptree-shake-icons=false -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug`

This is the last, there stucked forever

And what really interesting is, I tried to open it in Android Studio, and no gradle detect, I mean Gradle build forever, and if I type gradle clean or something no response at all

Comment: Did you tried flutter doctor ??

Comment: yes, no issue, except Android license but that is not the problem. I have been using Flutter since 1.5  year.