# i have problem with my flutter app when i run the code gradle task takes too long i tried flutter doctor ,it says that all things is right ,then error

Tags: android, flutter, debugging, gradle

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
```

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\tyous\StudioProjects\untitled\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check'.
> Could not create plugin of type 'VersionCheckPlugin'.
> > Could not generate a decorated class for type VersionCheckPlugin.
> > Lcom/android/ide/common/repository/GradleVersion;

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 51s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37091489/15117201

Comment: Take a look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63920645/16728483)

Answer (score 1):

if you run the first time it will download the grandle documentation. after that it wont take a long time

Answer (score 0):

Just wait for some time, if you code is right , it will run on your Virtual Emulator soon. Android Studio does take time to load and personally lags on my PC if I am doing something simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to connect your personal device in Android Studio. It might give you quicker results.

Coming back to your error, does this help?
[Android Studio - Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086806/android-studio-failed-to-apply-plugin-id-com-android-application?rq=1)