# where could i find flutter SDK Min and mix in VS Code

Tags: android, flutter, dart, debugging

[image]

where should i find minSdkVersion from 16 to 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android/app/build.gradle

it will look like this

```
defaultConfig {*
        applicationId "***"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName*
    }
```

Comment: can you help me to solve my flutter running Gradle task assembledebug? I am using VS CODE when I code flutter run in VS CODE terminal it installs my app right in my real phone. when I hit F5 key for debugging it stuck on running Gradle task assembledebug or some time on 'build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk'.and my app just show me black screen in phone. what should I do I am student I don't know how to solve this issue, if you have any flutter developer friend please discuss this issue so that I would  continue my coding

Comment: @M.Shahzad Check out this thread. Try those solutions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59516408/flutter-app-stuck-at-running-gradle-task-assembledebug

Comment: I solve this Issue when I Change my device, I mean my mobile. at first, I used a VIVO device for debugging it didn't work well but now I changed to Samsung now it works fine. somebody on FACEBOOK solves my problem. thank you for your effort