# Flutter app got stuck at building and installing (error type 3)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I just got into learning Flutter for android app development.
I tried test app which was prepared from the official document.

https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/test-drive?tab=vscode

At the first time it worked fine. But after I once deleted the app in my device manually and tried to reinstall it, the app got stuck.

> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

I tried rebooting computer and phone, and deleting /build and /.gradle directories. Some old articles suggested deleting app in all users, but I could not find any guest accounts in my phone.

flutter doctor said `No issues found!`

flutter run -v resulted like below.

```
[ +124 ms] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x20000000 cmp=com.example.my_app/.MainActivity (has extras) }
                        Error type 3
                        Error: Activity class {com.example.my_app/com.example.my_app.MainActivity} does not exist.
[        ] Waiting for VM Service port to be available...
```

When I made an exact same app with a name of 'newapp' instead of 'my_app', it worked at the first time. And after once deleted, it worked again. But after once more deleted, it resulted the same error.

I think there are some remnants of apps in my phone, but I cannot figure out where to find them.

Comment: This question has already been answered I believe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59516408/flutter-app-stuck-at-running-gradle-task-assembledebug

Comment: I did almost all options that were suggested on that post. `flutter clean`, deleting directories, enabling fire wall for both vscode and android studio.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: remove app using adb

But why does normal delete make problem? Should handle this problem.