# Launching lib\main.dart on RMX2151 in debug mode... Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Stuck

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

When I run:

$ flutter run
I'm getting a prompt on my mobile device asking if I want to install the app on my device. I give yes, then nothing happens!
[image]
It's stuck here:

Launching lib\main.dart on RMX2151 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Then nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter App stuck at "Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59516408/flutter-app-stuck-at-running-gradle-task-assembledebug)